# Encoding XML file breaks at special Latin characters

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file which I am attaching in my site library. The XML has latin characters so I am encoding it using this method `item.Attachments.Add("xyz.xml", Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(writerXml.ToString()));`

The issue is when I am trying to open the file in Browser it is breaking where the  special characters are occuring. It gives error as **Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet.**.

I would like to know how to fix this issue and why I am not able to generate it in browser?

Trying to add declaration using the below code :

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument();
            doc.Declaration = new XDeclaration("1.0","ISO-8859-1", null);
            XElement element = new XElement("webapp", new XAttribute("name", webApp.Name), new XAttribute("id", webApp.Id),
                           MyInformation;
            doc.Add(element);
            return doc.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Please post a reproducible example (XML +XSLT). And state which browser you are using.

Comment: With IE I get the exact value ( ie. the special character) where the file breaks. With Chrome I get the error with row and column number

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the encoding of the file isn't what the browser thinks it is.

I can't really see why you would want to use iso-8859-1 these days rather than utf-8, but if that's your choice, you need to make sure that (a) the XML declaration at the start of the file declares it as iso-8859-1, and (b) that there's no conflicting declaration in the HTTP headers when the file is served. My guess (with very little evidence) is that there's no XML declaration on the file so the browser is assuming UTF-8.

Comment: so what you say is that if I add at the starting of XML generation the line <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> ....it should work?

I am doing ISO-8859-1 as it is already implemented in the code to handle the Latin characters

Comment: Well I can certainly say that if the file uses iso-8859-1 encoding and DOESN'T have an XML declaration at the start then it WON'T work. Fix that first and see whether there are any other issues. However, building an XML file this way by hand probably isn't a good idea anyway: there are lots of other things you can get wrong, like escaping. Better to use a library for the purpose.

Comment: Ok..Thanks for the guidance.. I am building the XML through code and i am able to open it in browser when there is no special characters. So I will fix the same in code to get the starting tag. Will update once I have the result. thanks again!!

Comment: I am trying to add the tag using the code ( edited in the question).. But what output I am getting does not contain the declaration. Using C# code, Any idea what am i missing?

Comment: Hi I was able to add the header in the file but it now throws a different error :

Switch from current encoding to specified encoding not supported. Error processing resource 'http://xyz.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="yes"?>

Why my ISO code is getting converted to utf-16? Are both same?

Comment: New problem, needs a new question. Explain it from first principles so people don't have to wade through the past history.

Comment: Ok..Thanks for your help.. though the issue is not resolved I got a way to start.